# I think I messed up moving my home directory to another drive

Tags: home-directory

So yesterday I installed Ubuntu on my computer and removed Windows. I also formatted the drive with windows files after I finished installing Ubuntu. But the thing is that I accidentally installed Ubuntu on some extra Intel Optane drive that doesn’t have much storage. I used this YouTube tutorial to move my home directory to the other drive: https://youtu.be/lPJhUonbCKA. I should also probably mention that my drive that I had Windows didn’t have any partitions and it’s just one thing. Now when I log in to Amy account, it’s as if I am just setting up Ubuntu and it shows the pop up that comes up when you first install Ubuntu. It happens every time I turn the computer on. Does anybody know how I can finish this process or fix what is going on right now? Thank you.

Comment: Since you just installed then certainly you have nothing to loose by installing again with the proper partitions as you want. Installing in the Optane drive isn't at all bad but yes, you want to have /home in the bigger driver and only / in the Optane. Use "something else" to create and/or select the partitions you want, both ESP and / may remain in the Optane, create or select as home the /home in the bigger drive and install, it's that simple and much faster than fixing whatever you did wrong before.

Comment: Ok @ChanganAuto what exactly do you mean by “something else” Thanks for the comment, I’m one step closer to finishing this. Assuming I need to get a usb and reinstall, I already formatted the USB I used to install Linux for the first time and I don’t think I can use another computer at the moment for this. I am also not able to open any web browsers on Ubuntu and I don’t have any other OS on my PC.

Comment: You can use gparted as a GUI to partition your drive into usable pieces. `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: Or, 'something else' can refer to the installation step when you are choosing how the installer will format the drive for you. You then have choices on how to partition the drive, if you need to do that again.

Comment: "Something else is an option during the Ubuntu installation. Other are "erase and install..." or "install alongside" when other OS is detected.  However neither allows creating a separated /home partition. For that you need to choose "something else" and create and/or select your partitions manually.

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions default to swap file but will use swap partition if you have it:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @smilingfrog could you please elaborate on what I need to do? I already have gparted, but I'm not exactly sure what to do

Comment: Also, I think that what is going on is that I have my home directory on one drive, but it thinks that it is still on the other drive

Comment: It depends on how far along you are in the setup, and what you have on the partition for your /home directory. You may need to edit the entry in /etc/fstab so that the home directory is loaded instead of the home directory on the original / partition.

Comment: Reading your question again, perhaps this is a Grub issue? you might get help [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing); you may just need to run `sudo update-grub` to recognize the old install.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment above, it seems to me that you have set up the entire installation on a single drive, but then subsequently wanted to have your /home directory located on a separate partition. This is a good practice to have.

Assuming you are booting into a new install, and not booting from a live .iso file either from a USB or a hard drive image (I can't tell from the description above), you are now faced with the task of moving your /home from the single / partition to a separate home partition. To confirm this, when you boot up your machine, you should be presented with a GRUB menu, and then once that loads, it should boot up Ubuntu. When you are installing, you should have a completely different set of steps. If these steps are being represented to you, then the GRUB set up is not recognising the install, or your boot media is still loaded, or your CMOS is not booting in the right order.

But I am assuming you have successfully installed Ubuntu to a single partition, and want to move your /home directory.

The partitions you have available are not necessarily all enabled. Linux uses `/etc/fstab` to list the partitions, and their mountpoints. Here, you can add the partition holding your new /home directory.

What you need to do is identify the UUID of the partition for the new /home partition. You can get this by running gparted, or you can get it from the command line using `blkid`.

Once you identify the UUID of the new partition, you need to add a line to the /etc/fstab file, such as follows:

```
UUID=a75c927c-YOUR-UUID-b561-3e7dc406d0c8  /home  ext4 defaults,auto  0  2
```

Which assumes your /home partition is identified by the UUID given, and is formatted as ext4.

Once the `/etc/fstab` file is updated, you will need to reboot your system, and the new partition will be mounted overtop of the original /home directory. You will not be able to access the information in that old /home when the new partition is mounted.

gparted will let you move and resize partitions, generate new UUIDs, create labels, and format partitions. There are many other commands which do the same thing, but it is pretty user friendly if you are just beginning.

I hope this helps a bit.